# How do I block IE11 visitors from visiting my page? htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, browser, explorer

I've added the following to my .htaccess file for bit.ly/29bG9uv.  However it doesn't seem to be blocking me when visiting bit.ly/29bG9uv in Internet Explorer 11.

Ideas? Need to block IE11 visitors to bit.ly/29bG9uv

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>
# END GD-SSL


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: why are you blocking one browser?

Answer (score 1):

IE11 uses the string "Trident" to identify its browser engine. You can use the following code to block IE11

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*Trident.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403]
```

You may also want to block older versions of IE. In order to do that, use the string "MSIE"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*MSIE.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403]
```

If you want to redirect all IE users to a separate page, which for example might ask them to download a different browser, you can use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*MSIE.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) ie.html

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*Trident.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) ie.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to block IE browsers:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} *MSIE*
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://example.com/ie/ [L]
RewriteRule  ^/$ http://example.com/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Great, but I need to block only IE 11, no other versions.

Comment: anybody know how to block IE11 only?  ?   ?   ?

Answer (score 0):

To block `IE11` user agent, you can use :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} IE11 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]
```

This blocks the whole site for  IE11, they get a 403 forbidden error. if you want to block a specific page, then you can use :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} IE11 [NC]
RewriteRule ^page - [R=403,L]
```